# regular expression on file name with bracket numbering?

Tags: regex

I am just a noob on reg exp and I am trying to learn them. If I have a file name like this:

```
myfile(1).jpg or myfile(21).jpg
```

How can I extract with an reg exp (php or javascript) the `file name [myfile]`, `bracket numbering [1]` and `extension [jpg]`?

Comment: I can extac numbering with this /\((.*?)\)/, but still not file name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^(.*?)(?:\((\d+)\))?\.(.+)$/
```

`$1` variable will contain the filename.
`$2` variable will contain the numbering (if it is available or else it will be undefined or null).
`$3` variable will contain the extension.

Comment: actually this works better. thank you. it get even when file name is sadasd(asdasd(23).jpg. you seems to be a guru of regexpt

Comment: I am not understanding what is the meaning of /^(.*?) in particular the first "?". Just I am trying to decodificode this reg exp.

Comment: `^` and `$` are starting and ending anchors which means match from the starting and ending of the string. `?` in `(.*?)` is used for `ungreedy` matching. `?:` is to tell the regex to not create any backreference/groups. It is hard to explain everything here. A good resource is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: Thank you very much Aziz, you are very polite.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
^(.*?)\((\d+)\)\.(.*)$
```

1. First group is filename
2. Second group - number of file
3. Last group - extension without dot

Answer (score 0):

Which language are you using regexes in?
Which variant of regular expression syntax?

Here is your sample using perl:

```
my $s = 'myfile(21).jpg';
$s =~ m/^(.*?)\((\d+)\)\.(.*)$/;
print "found 1=$1, 2=$2, 3=$3\n";
```

It returns:

```
found 1=myfile, 2=21, 3=jpg
```

`^(.*?)\(`: stores a group with shortest string up to the literal "(", starting from beggining of your string

`(\d+)`: stores a group: sequence of numbers

`\.(.*)$` stores a group: string after literal "." up to end of your string (file extension)